# Which Facebook C# SDK? Official (github) or unofficial (codeplex)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

They both have the same name and use the new Graph API, but which is better for ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms? The official SDK hasn't been updated in a few months, but the one on Codeplex was just updated last week. Does anyone have experience with both that could offer an opinion?

https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm curious, why was this was closed after being answered more than 1.5 years ago?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've worked with facebooksdk.  The source code is well engineered and it works great for us.

The facebooksdk also allows you to use the new **dynamic** type when working with the Graph API which makes it really easy to work.

After logging in with the Javascript SDK, it is really easy to get info about the user.

```
FacebookApp facebook = new FacebookApp(GetFacebookSettings());
if (facebook.Session != null)
{
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.fields = "id,first_name,last_name,birthday,email";
    dynamic result = facebook.Api("me", parameters);

    // do something with the user's name...
    string firstName = result.first_name;
}
```

Comment: The other thing to note is that the official Facebook C# SDK does not have any support for authorization. If you use that you are on your own when it comes to getting the access token. The Facebook C# SDK on codeplex takes care of this for you.

Comment: @Nathan Totten: How can you do this?. I am currently working on a Canvas App in webforms and I can't figure out how to use the codeplex Facebook C# SDK to get a token.

Comment: @Nathan: Please check my question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226852/get-oauth-2-0-access-token-from-asp-net-iframe-canvas-application

Answer (score 1):

I vote for facebooksdk from codeplex. It is regularly updated and bug fixed.

Its also very easy to work with. I recommend codeplex facebook C# sdk

Here is a code repository with well tested code for working with it [facebook C# sdk code samples](http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/)