# Server authentication

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, sdk, server-side

Is there a way to create access token for user?

I know that it is possible to get user information by this code:

```
var client = new FacebookClient("key");
var me = client.Get("me");
```

but how to create key for user which doesn't have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these questions, they might help you.

[facebook-C#-sdk MVC "Hello World" app - how to get access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227964/facebook-c-sdk-mvc-hello-world-app-how-to-get-access-token)

[(Facebook C# SDK) Problem getting an access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273425/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-problem-getting-an-access-token)